# Wicket: Create dynamic anchor links to rows in a data table

Tags: java, html, dynamic, hyperlink, wicket

I need to create a list dynamic of anchor links to rows in a data table.

I started with a (sorted) data table as per this example

[A Simple Sortable DataTable Example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Simple+Sortable+DataTable+Example)

The "FooPanel" should contain one link for each row in the data table.

The code so far is:

```
public class FooPanel extends Panel {

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

    private Link<String> createLink(String linkName, final String name)
    {
        final Link<String> l = new Link<String>(linkName) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
            }
        };
        l.setBody(Model.of(name));
        return l;
    }

    public FooPanel(final String id, IModel<List<String>> model) {
        super(id);

        final List<String> linkList = model.getObject();

        final Label myLabel = new Label("myLabel", "this is my label");
        myLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        this.add(myLabel);

        final RepeatingView view = new RepeatingView("fooPanelItems");

        for (final String linkLabel:linkList)
        {
            final Link<String> link = createLink(view.newChildId(), String.format("[ %s ]", linkLabel));
            link.setAnchor(myLabel);
            link.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            view.add(link);
        }

        this.add(view);
    }
}

private class LazyFooPanel extends AjaxLazyLoadPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final IModel<List<String>> m_model;

    private LazyFooPanel(final String id, IModel<List<String>> model)
    {
        super(id, model);
        m_model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getLazyLoadComponent(final String markupId)
    {
        return new FooPanel(markupId, m_model);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onComponentLoaded(final Component component, final AjaxRequestTarget target)
    {
        target.add(component);
    }
}
```

I am having troubles linking my dynamic links with items in the data table - can you help?

Comment: What problems exactly you experience ?

Comment: I don't know how to identify the component (table row) to set the anchor "to" instead of "link.setAnchor(myLabel)"

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you add a `Link` to the `RepeatingView`. I think you need to add a `Panel` to it instead. This Panel will have its own `Label`, the `Link` and anything else that you need on a row.

If you don't want to use a new Panel then you can use WebMarkupContainer and keep the markup in `FooPanel.html`.